# View Which Files Were Loaded

Tags: php, include, phpstorm, xdebug, require

Is there a way to view which files were loaded in a project? I'm using PHPStorm with Xdebug, and I want to see if there are any superfluous files, and which are needed. The program runs, but there are many files in the framework that are not being used, how can I see which files are necessary for the application, and which are extra?

Comment: Do you mean something like [get_included_files](http://www.php.net/get_included_files)?

Comment: Ok thats great. No need to downvote ;)

Comment: searching google for `php View Which Files Were Loaded` which is exactly the title of your question along with "php" finds the manual page for that php function as the first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple PHP function for this, get_included_files():

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php